# Orbeon forms convert number from textfield into words?

Tags: orbeon

i am creating orbeon form, so i write a script that can convert number into words,now is it possible to pass the parameter url in orbeon to read a text field and convert the number in to word in another textfield or populate another textfield from the url?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need. If you need get URL parameter you can use `xxf:get-request-parameter()` (https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/extension-functions/extension-http#xxf-get-request-parameter). For example set this funciton as calculated value for some Text Field, publish form and test it in Runner.

If it not correct answer, please write more information about you problem.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your response,i have an api parameter that can convert number into words,so im looking for how to get the value in textfield and populate the other text field with the conversion .Any explicit explanation from you will go a long way for me..

Comment: Sorry, I´m again confused about what do you need. If you need copy text from one textfield to other, set calculate value to example `$contol-1` (here is example for formulas https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/formulas/formulas-examples) If you need fill text from one in another more comprehensive textfield (set one dynamic word into whole sentence) use Explanatory Text and in settings set template parameter form original Textfield (https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/advanced/template-syntax). If is still not your answer for your question please try to give me more information.

Comment: Hi David,i need to be more explicit in my explanation this time.This is what i'm trying to achieve,i have an api url that convert number into words,now i have 2 texfield of txtAmount as input and txtWord as output.Now im looking for how i can input numbers in txt amount and it should automatically populate txtWord in the output. like if i pass (200) in the amount input and it will trigger txtWord as (two hundred) as output, Any help of favor you can do for me?

Comment: Hi, yes now I understand. You need create HTTP Service and Action. Read this documentation:
https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/advanced/services-and-actions/http-services
https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/advanced/services-and-actions/actions
and I create simple form for you here:
https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/b0e5cfad508bdf5db7d691e34a186fdfda13e20d
I think all what you need can be set throw builder (GET/POST, input param, read result, ...).

Comment: Thank you very much David.You are one in a million and your kind is rare,you walk me through the process like a baby and you weren't bored providing solution.My problem is 90% solved,please i need one more implementation from you? i have an api that i uploaded the script on,i want you to look at it and help me with the final adjustment,because right now i can pick the node from xml list,but i'm having problem in getting the value from the converter in the url.Please last time help.

Comment: Try save full response to dataset (https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/features/datasets). Next add XForms inspector to look at full dataset (https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/xforms-inspector). Then you must write own Xpath expresion and test in Inspector (https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp). If you dont have for some reason response in body but header try `event('response-headers')[lower-case(name) = 'your_header_name']/value`. But better is change you API. It should be POST request. I updated example, look at it again. I hope with this you can finish this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much David,i really appreciate you for your kindness,please where can i find you or if i can support you on patreon or anywhere else.

Comment: Hi David,i need your help once more,please how do i implement user authentication,i dont just want anyone to have access to the url as i want to implement login by users before the can have access to the form,if you can help me with a sample of what i need to include in web.xml,local-properties e.t.c,i have tried it and its not looking good for me here.Any help will be great thanks,this is my final implementation on Orbeon.Please help..

Comment: I am having HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report
Message The requested resource [/orbeon] is not available
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.I'm having the above error while trying to implement basic authentication.Please i need your help this time?????